# Command line RDP call CMD on target machine

Tags: c#, windows, windows-7, remote-desktop

I need to remote into ~50 machines and run a batch file. Is there any way I can start up an RDP session and call cmd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to use RDP to access these machines, there are shells for mstsc.exe that allow command line auto-login and running a program upon connection. One that comes to mind is Remote Desktop Plus. You could use a batch script to log in to the given machines with the following syntax:

```
rdp /v:computer /u:username /p:password /start:"pathtoscript/script.bat"
```

Download from http://www.donkz.nl/

Comment: Actually you don't need a third party tool (moved answer below for better formatting)

Answer (score 6):

Windows Remote Shell is what you want;

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163506.aspx

Once setup, you can go `WinRS -r:MYSERVER "cmd.exe"` which will run cmd.exe on the remote machine and bring you a remoted console session locally. Alternatively, you could just run any other command directly on the box instead.

Actually, if you are *need* to use RDP (and I wouldn't bother just to run a batch file if I could avoid it) you could run a shell (or any other command) *without* a 3rd party program. Just run mstsc.exe, choose an alternate shell and save the RDP file.

The key settings you need are looking for are;

```
full address:s:yourserver.domain.com:3389
alternate shell:s:c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe
```